# How to create non-unique index on column in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a non-unique index on the `file_name` column.  I'm expecting a high cardinality, say for 1,000 rows, there are 950 unique file names.

```
file_collection = Table ('file_collection', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('full_path', String, unique=True, nullable=False),
    Column('file_name', String, index=True, nullable=False)
)
```

My dialect is sqlite. When I create the table, a non-unique key is not created on the `file_name` column

```
CREATE TABLE file_collection (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        full_path VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        file_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (full_path)
)
```

How can I create a non-unique key on the `file_name` column?

Comment: How are you getting the `CREATE TABLE` code that you showed in the question?

Comment: The second argument to this function `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that SQLite requires you to create a non-unique index as a separate statement rather than in the actual `CREATE TABLE` statement like some RDBMs allow. Assuming I have the following table:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
```

The creation will run as follows.

```
2014-01-03 17:28:48,229 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("users")
2014-01-03 17:28:48,229 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-01-03 17:28:48,229 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2014-01-03 17:28:48,230 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-01-03 17:28:48,230 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2014-01-03 17:28:48,230 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_users_email ON users (email)
2014-01-03 17:28:48,230 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-01-03 17:28:48,231 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Note that the CREATE TABLE statement does not show the index being created, but it IS being created in a follow-up statement slightly after.